# Javascript function in wordpress page won't work

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have made a script that takes a year as parameter and then prints out the difference from current year in words. The word part I haven't done myself, I found a bit of code that worked which I used.

When I try the code in for example jsfiddle and call it with

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = yearDiff(1968);
```

and it works when I use this HTML code.

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

But when I try to run it within a Wordpress page for testing it doesn't work.
Here is what I insert to the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = ['','one ','two ','three ','four ', 'five ','six ','seven ','eight ','nine ','ten ','eleven ','twelve ','thirteen ','
    var b = ['', '', 'twenty','thirty','forty','fifty', 'sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety'];

    function yearDiff(startYear) {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();     
        num = currentYear - startYear;

        n = ('000000000' + num).substr(-9).match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{2})$/);
        if (!n) return;
        var str = '';
        str += (n[5] != 0) ? ((str != '') ? 'and ' : '') + (a[Number(n[5])] || b[n[5][0]] + ' ' + a[n[5][1]]) : '';
        return str;
    } 
    yearDiff(1975);
</script>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I copied/pasted your code into CodePen, and it works fine other than the things that @joaquin made below about your array not being completed and not doing anything with the return value.  see it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbOwYv?editors=101

Comment: I used your code which is much alike the one I tested on jsfiddle and pasted it into my wordpress page, but I still won't get a output on the wordpress page. I don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: Do you get any errors in the JS Console?  Have you tried doing something like `alert(yearDiff(1975));` to see if the code runs?  In your example above you simple call `yearDiff(1975)` without using the value it returns anywhere.  Are you using the value properly?

Comment: I tried `alert(yearDiff(1975));`
with no luck. But when I try `alert('test');` without the rest of the code it works.

Comment: What does "with no luck" mean?  Are you getting an error, if the function undefined?  It sounds like this is not an issue with your code, it's an issue with getting your code to work within Wordpress.  Look at the page source and see if it's being included as you expect.

Comment: The problem was the blank lines, after I removed them everything seems to work. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last example you're just calling the function (`yearDiff(1975);`) but doing nothing with the return value..

Are you missing some code, or is just this your problem?

**EDIT**

I was looking again at your code and you have this:
`var a = ['','one ','two ','three ','four ', 'five ','six ','seven ','eight ','nine ','ten ','eleven ','twelve ','thirteen ','`

You didn't finish your array.. You surely have an error in your javascript console yelling some `unexpected token` or something like that....

Comment: I must have done something wrong when I pasted the code, the arrays looks like this
`var a = ['','one ','two ','three ','four ', 'five ','six ','seven ','eight ','nine ','ten ','eleven ','twelve ','thirteen ','fourteen ','fifteen ','sixteen ','seventeen ','eighteen ','nineteen '];
var b = ['', '', 'twenty','thirty','forty','fifty', 'sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety'];`

So how do I print the return value? I'm new to Javascript

Comment: Where do you want to print your value?

Comment: You can use, for example, what you got in the question: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = yearDiff(1968);`

Comment: The problem were blank lines in wordpress, without them it worked.